# Import json files in R and convert into csv

Tags: json, r

I have json format file in my hard disk. I want to read this json file and convert it into dataframe.
I have used this code:

```
file <- 'users-20-30.JSON'
con = file(file, "r")
input <- readLines(con, -1L)
business.training <- lapply(X=input,fromJSON)

df<-do.call("cbind", business.training)
df<-data.frame(df)
```

But I am not getting in proper dataframe format. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: JSON is a very rich file format, and unless anyone on here is psychic or has hacked into your PC, we have no idea what your file looks like. Can you post it? Or some of it? Or let us hack into your PC to see it for ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful to look through some of the examples of the `fromJSON()` function.

```
library(RJSONIO)
?fromJSON
```